# Showing a number is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra

Working through some Commutative algebra questions, came across this question and wanted to know if my thinking is right. The question:

Show that $(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[6]{7})^5 - 7\sqrt[4]{5}$ satisfies a monic polynomial with integer coefficients. I went with showing it is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$. I gave the monic polynomial for $7\sqrt[4]{5}$, which leaves us to show $(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[6]{7})^5$ is integral.

I figured there's two possibilities:

1) If $\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt[6]{7}$ are integral over $\mathbb{Z}$, the entire thing is. Can write down the monic polynomials for these numbers easily.

2) We can expand it via the binomial theorem (which I did), then I came up with monic polynomials for each of the terms and say the whole thing is integral as a result.

Am I on the right track here? Is doing 2) unnecessary? Am I even doing the right thing to begin with? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Step 2 is unnecessary, because algebraic integers form a ring, and therefore sums, powers, and differences of algebraic integers are still integral. As long as you show that $\sqrt{3}$, $\sqrt[6]{7}$ and $\sqrt[4]{5}$ are integral, the rest follows from ring axioms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1, we can write $x^2-3$ and $x^6-7$ as monic polynomials with each of those as a root.